# Indirectly defined objects to a list

Tags: r, list, indirect-objects

I have a variable whose name and value are both determined dynamically. I want to append that variable to a list, so I need to express it in the form `list(x)`. My difficulty is defining what `x` should be.
So, for example, if the value of the name is given by the variable `a`, and the value is `b`, I have both

```
a <- "name"
b <- 3
```

But then I get this result:

```
list(a = b)
```

> $a
> [1] 3

The value is correct but the name is not. I want the list to look behind the variable `a` to its current value, which is "name".
How do I do that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lst` from `dplyr` as the expression on the lhs of `=` is only evaluated literally and not the value stored int it.

```
library(dplyr)
lst(!! a:= b)
$name
[1] 3
```

Or with `setNames/names<-` from `base R`

```
setNames(list(b), a)
$name
[1] 3
`names<-`(list(b), a)
$name
[1] 3
```

Or create the list first and then rename

```
lst1 <- list(b)
names(lst1) <- a
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `structure`.

```
a <- 'name'; b <- 3

structure(as.list(b), names=a)
# $name
# [1] 3
```

It generalizes well for multiple pair-wise values.

```
a <- c('name1', 'name2'); b <- c(3, 4)

structure(as.list(b), names=a)
# $name1
# [1] 3
# 
# $name2
# [1] 4
```